# angular routing issue with custom mod folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, routes, edit

This is my routing code:

```
.when('/:mod/:page*/', {
      templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
          return 'pages/'+$routeParams.mod+'/' + $routeParams.page + '.html';
      }
})
```

if the url is

```
/users/add
```

it will load html from pages/users/add.html

Now the issue is Say for example I have a list page list.html with list data

```
id - name        - action
1  - John        - Edit
```

When I now click on edit I need to go to the edit.html page as well as I need to pass and get the id to that html.

How can this be achievable ?
Do I need to edit my routing ?

NOTE: 
I am using ng-route for routing.

assume edit.html has a separate controller and the list.html has a separate controller.

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass id in the edit link

```
...
<a href="/edit/{{id}}">Edit</a>

$routeProvider
.when('/edit/:id', {
  templateUrl: 'edit.html',
  controller: 'EditController',
....

app.controller('EditController', function($routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams.id);
    ....
});
```

Comment: For me to use stateParams I may have to use ui-route instead of ng-route right ?

Comment: are you sure 

 'ui-sref'

will work at the anchor tag with $routeParams in the controller ?

Comment: should be 'href'. Updated my answers. hope it  works for you this time.